# Test for availability of Google Maps Flash API

Tags: flash, google-maps

I'm trying to write a test page which a customer can send us to identify whether they can use various parts of our site. Typical support stuff I guess.

Anyway, the test for flash is straightforward enough, but can anyone suggest how I might test if they can access the Google Maps API on their browser?

Any help appreciated as I have hit a brick wall here.

Comment: yes dw, I am probably not explaining very well, your sort of right of course, if we have flash and connectivity it should all just work. I think I'll give Chris' GBrowserIsCompatible() a go though, which is probably closer to what I should have been asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem, but I wouldn't think you'd have to check anything to know whether or not the Maps Flash API works.  If the browser accessing your site has the correct Flash player version, then the Maps stuff should just work, since you're the one building/delivering the swf that consumes the google maps swc.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API includes a function to determine whether the browser is compatible:

[GBrowserIsCompatible()](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GBrowserIsCompatible)